# How do I secure (SSRS ) reporting service instance when it is installed in same virtual machine as database?

Tags: azure, security, networking, reporting-services, azure-nsg

I am working on architecture where `web application` will talk to `database`.

The web application is in `VM1`
The database is on `VM2` as shown below

[image]

I am following below security best practises,

- `VM 1` can accept traffic from any source. The protocol will be TCP, and it's going to only accept traffic on port 80, which HTTP, and 443, which is HTTPS
- `DB subnet` is only expected to accept traffic from the web application, so I am only allowing traffic from subnet number 1. The protocol is TCP, and I'm going to only accept traffic on the standard SQL Server port, which is 1433.

Now the challenge is due to `Reporting server 2012`, which has a below drawback.

> Reporting service and database has to be in same Virtual Machine. [Drawback overcome only in reporting service 2017 which we can't afford now] and it required port 80 to be opened so that `web application` can be accessed by a `web application` which is deployed on VM1

Now I have to enable port 80 on DB server, that is not good for security.

So what shall be the best practise?

One approach I am thinking to change the SSRS port from 80 to something XXXX, and allow that port. Is it the right way?  Or Do I have to upgrade to SSRS 2017 which helps to move reporting service to web application VM?  What will be the best approach?

**Update**: Database VM port is enabled in `Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced security` settings. and it works only when "Public" checkbox is checked. It does not work on the private option.  Keeping `public` is not risky?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default http port 80 is generally used by web application, in my opinion, change port is easy and simple deployment. The traffic between the virtual network to virtual network is routed through the Azure backbone network which is also safe. You could change the SSRS port refer to the solution in [this blog](https://seankilleen.com/2012/11/how-to-stop-sql-server-reporting-services-from-using-port-80-on-your-server-field-notes/) and update the port in the inbound rule of the NSG on the VM2.

If you want to use SSRS 2017, you might need to upgrade your SQL server, see [this note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/what-s-new-in-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-2017-reporting-services).

> You can only use the query designer for DAX with SSAS tabular data
>   sources built in SQL Server 2016+.

Comment: I have changed the port of SSRS, However, I see that pipeline works only when "firewall rule" is public  . I have updated the screenshot in question.

Comment: Is the ReportServerUrl public or private address? In technically, if you have NSG associated with subnet, you can secure the traffic going in or out from your azure subnet.

Comment: Do you still have any questions?

Comment: yes, let me get back with some analysis and accept the answer,